# Making a Delegate Call from One View Controller to Another

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

One of the things that I haven't done in Swift is use of a delegate.  So I'm trying to make a delegate call from one view controller to another to pass data.

I have two view controllers across two separate storyboards.  One is HomeViewController, the 1st view controller.  That's where the user is at right now.  Then he taps the right navigation item button to go to SettingsViewController, the 2nd view controller.  He then taps a navigation item button to go back to the 1st view controller.  On the way back, SettingsViewController sends an `Int` value to HomeViewController.  And what I have is the following.

```
// 1st view controller //
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, SettingsViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBAction func rightTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InitialController") as! UINavigationController
        let view = controller.topViewController as! SettingsViewController
        view.selectedRow = lineSelection
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InitialController") as! UINavigationController
        let settingsViewController = controller.topViewController as! SettingsViewController
        settingsViewController.delegate = self
    }

    func didChangeLine(number: Int) {
        print(number) // <<<<<<<<< not getting a delegate call
    }
}

// 2nd view controller //
protocol SettingsViewControllerDelegate {
    func didChangeLine(number: Int)
}

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectedRow = Int() // the row selected from a table view
    var rightButton = UIBarButtonItem()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Change", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(changeNumber))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = rightButton
    }

    // going back to 1st view controller (HomeViewController)
    func changeNumber() {
        self.delegate?.didChangeLine(selectedRow)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

I'm not getting a call when the user goes back from the 2nd (Settings) to the 1st view controller (Home).  I can pass data in a different approach, but I want to what I'm doing wrong with this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your changing the selected row value? if so, can you show more of the code?

Comment: @J. Koush I could set a magic number to didChangeLine.  The first view controller never receives it.

Comment: Yes.  And the user will be sent back to the 1st view controller.

Comment: Can you check with a debugger in `changeNumber()` method if the delegate isn't `nil`.

Comment: You are creating an instance of SettingsViewController in viewDidLoad and setting its delegate, but you aren't saving or presenting this instance of settings view controller. How do you present the settings view controller?

Comment: i guess he is presenting/pushing the controller from segue  @Paulw11

Comment: I just did quick test, and it works fine not sure what's going wrong in your code,here is the link to code that I have tried..
**[link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwaYgeDyEk3BaTJ0NW1xbFZ2Zzg**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `prepareForSegue` in  1st viewcontroller for passing  1st viewcontroller ref to secondviewcontroller delegate property.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SettingsViewController
        viewController.delegate = self
}
```

In `HomeViewController` `viewDidLoad` code doesn't make any sense because you're performing segue from storyboard.

**UPDATED**

```
@IBAction func rightTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InitialController") as! UINavigationController
    let view = controller.topViewController as! SettingsViewController
    view.delegate = self

   view.selectedRow = lineSelection
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
}
```

and you can directly get the SettingViewController ref. just set viewcontroller storyboard id and get it like this

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
 let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InitialController") as! UINavigationController

let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController
```

Comment: I am not using the segue to transition from the 1st view controller to the 2nd.

Comment: then how will you presenting second view controller from 1st controller?

Comment: I've updated the code.  See @IBAction func rightTapped(sender: AnyObject)

Comment: updated code.  view.delegate = self . you need to assign delegate to self before pushing.

Comment: Thanks.  How so if you allow me to ask?

Answer (score 2):

```
@IBAction func rightTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InitialController") as! UINavigationController
        let view = controller.topViewController as! SettingsViewController
        view.selectedRow = lineSelection
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
    }
```

Change to  :

```
@IBAction func rightTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InitialController") as! UINavigationController
        let view = controller.topViewController as! SettingsViewController
        view.selectedRow = lineSelection
view.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this [Protocol-Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx8cP3i5d-syR0FYcFpfaHYyOTg/view?usp=sharing), I've simulated the same scenario of calling HomeViewController's 'didChangeLine' function as shown in below image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change follwing method in SettingsViewController class : -

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(changeNumber))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = rightButton
    }
```

Comment: Why would I want to do that?

Comment: Because you are not call "changeNumber" method for back button. You are calling "changeNumber" method for right button not for back button.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, here I've created a variable settingsViewController and I'm setting it in the `viewDidLoad()` method and using it when the user taps the right button, instead of creating a new settingsViewController.

```
// 1st view controller //
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, SettingsViewControllerDelegate {

    var settingsViewController: SettingsViewController? 
    // creating a variable so that we can use it in the IBOutlet 
    // method after setting it in the viewDidLoad() method

    @IBAction func rightTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        settingsViewController.selectedRow = lineSelection
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsViewController, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InitialController") as! UINavigationController
        settingsViewController = controller.topViewController as? SettingsViewController
        settingsViewController.delegate = self
    }

    func didChangeLine(number: Int) {
        print(number) 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the purpose of doing that.  Besides, the application will crash when it transition from the first to the second view controller.

Comment: What's the crash message?